# jQuery not validating the very first field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my form jQuery validation seems to skip the very first field. If I change the order of fields, it's still the first one that is not validated. I've spent some time (more than I'd like to admit) googling around but couldn't find anything helpful. Any ideas?

Screen shots:

[image: form1]
[image: form2]

Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddAgent", "Settings", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-main" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactName)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactName)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    ...
```

Model:

```
public class RegisterAgentModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contact name")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Email address cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

Generated html:

```
<form action="/Settings/AddAgent" class="form-main" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="w_LGr9b6kXZ3M9dtKT5jNOWYCrLLQD97mH8DQAZ3RxozSLWpwS3E6k7oBqJu5-lnhXqbg7pBDDbOfo5nWTUqWuC732uvPdmYRXhmEApvOKQ1" />    <div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />
    <label for="UserName">User name</label>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Contact name field is required." id="ContactName" name="ContactName" type="text" value="" />
    <label for="ContactName">Contact name</label>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ContactName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-email="Invalid Email Address" data-val-length="Email address cannot be longer than 100 characters." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-required="The Email address field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
    <label for="Email">Email address</label>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

After validate:

```
<div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
    <label for="UserName">User name</label>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Contact name field is required." id="ContactName" name="ContactName" type="text" value="" class="input-validation-error">
    <label for="ContactName">Contact name</label>
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="ContactName" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="ContactName" class="">The Contact name field is required.</span></span>
</div>
```

And first div is still the same

Comment: check in console whether span for validation is created or not???

Comment: yes it is generated, yet not triggered: `<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>`

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML ?

Comment: updated with html, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the order of fields, it's still the first one that is not validated. So the validation message or error message should be overridden by some HTML element. By using Firebug you can check it.

Comment: Thanks, I added html in the update. As you can see, message is not overridden, it just doesn't appear at all.